# MonoDevelop debugger not attaching to WebAPI service

Tags: mono, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api, monodevelop, owin

I've got a Console application that is running an OWIN self hosted WebAPI service. When I run in in the Ubuntu command line every thing works fine however when I try and debug it in MonoDevelop, the main function just executes and then exits. I want it to remain debugging so I can make requests against the WebAPI but can seem to get it to not exit.

Is there something that I should be doing to make the debugger attach to the entire program?

Answer (score 0):

How old is your MonoDevelop?

I just ran my MonoDevelop v5.11, and I can find the option "Attach to process" inside the "Run" menu. (This option was not present in prior versions, such as 4.0.x.)